# How to sort String array according to users input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, columnsorting

I tried to sort String array using users input of which column they want to edit. However, sorted array cannot be displayed. I do not know how to modify or where to modify. Here, String array is made from first name, last name, and middle initial. So, logic is comparing adjacent column and of former comes later alphabetically, there is a swap going on. If two array have the same string, then compare the next row and the same column and again a swap going on. ( this is only for the 1st and 2nd column)

And also I want to modify array according to user’s input of column they want to sort. Am I correctly using Scanner class?

Here’s my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Multi_dimensional_array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String students[][]= {{"Prachaya" , "Johnson" , "M"}, {"Hafsa" , "Pillips", "R" }, { "Junnosuke", "Andews", "D"}, {"Aithima" , "Peters", "H"}, {"Jenwiji", "Davis","J" }};
    int arrlen = students.length;
    System.out.println("original array is:" );
    System.out.println();
    for(int count1 = 0; count1 < arrlen; count1++) 
    {
        for(int count2 = 0; count2 < arrlen -2; count2++) 
        {
            System.out.print(students[count1][count2] + "   \t" );
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
    String temp = "";


    //This is sorted array according to user's input 

    int x = 0; int y = 0; 
    int column; 
    Scanner sc =new Scanner (‭System.in‬);

    //Ask user's imput of column he/she wants to edit
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please Enter the number of column you want to edit: ");
    column = sc.nextInt();

    if ( column == 1)
    {

        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        //swap array[0][0] and array [1][0] / [1][0] and [2][0] / [2][0] and [3][0] / [3][0] and [4][0] / [4][0] and [5][0] 
    if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y])> 0) 
    {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
    } 
    x = 0; y = 0; 
    //compare the top array with bottom strings  
    for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
        {
            temp = students[x][y] ; 
            students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
            students[x + j][y] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
            students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
            students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
            students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
            students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
        }
    else 
    {
        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y]) == 0)
        {
        if (students[x][y + 1].compareTo(students[x + 1][y + 1])> 0) 
        {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
        }
        x = 0; y = 0; 
        for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
        {
            if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
            {
                temp = students[x][y] ; 
                students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
                students[x + j][y] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
                students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
                students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
                students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
                students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

        }
        }
    }

    if ( column == 2)
        y = 1; 
    {

        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        //swap array[0][0] and array [1][0] / [1][0] and [2][0] / [2][0] and [3][0] / [3][0] and [4][0] / [4][0] and [5][0] 
    if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y])> 0) 
    {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
    } 
    x = 0; y = 1; 
    //compare the top array with bottom strings  
    for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
        {
            temp = students[x][y] ; 
            students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
            students[x + j][y] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
            students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
            students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
            students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
            students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
        }
    else 
    {
        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y]) == 0)
        {
        if (students[x][y + 1].compareTo(students[x + 1][y + 1])> 0) 
        {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
        }
        x = 0; y = 1; 
        for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
        {
            if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
            {
                temp = students[x][y] ; 
                students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
                students[x + j][y] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
                students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
                students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
                students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
                students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

        }
        }
    }

    if ( column == 3)
        y = 2; 
    {

        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        //swap array[0][0] and array [1][0] / [1][0] and [2][0] / [2][0] and [3][0] / [3][0] and [4][0] / [4][0] and [5][0] 
    if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y])> 0) 
    {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
    } 
    x = 0; y = 2; 
    //compare the top array with bottom strings  
    for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
        {
            temp = students[x][y] ; 
            students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
            students[x + j][y] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
            students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
            students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
            temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
            students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
            students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
        }
    else 
    {
        if( x < arrlen - 1)
        {
    for  (x = 0; x < arrlen; x++)
    {
        if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 1][y]) == 0)
        {
        if (students[x][y + 1].compareTo(students[x + 1][y + 1])> 0) 
        {
        temp = students[x][y] ; 
        students[x][y] = students[x + 1][y];
        students[x + 1][y] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
        students[x][y + 1] = students[x + 1][y + 1];
        students[x + 1][y + 1] = temp;
        temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
        students[x][y + 2] = students[x + 1][y + 2];
        students[x + 1][y + 2] = temp;
        }
        x = 0; y = 2; 
        for (int j = x + 2; j< arrlen; j++)
        {
            if (students[x][y].compareTo(students[x + 2][y])> 0 )
            {
                temp = students[x][y] ; 
                students[x][y] = students[x + j][y];
                students[x + j][y] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 1] ; 
                students[x][y + 1] = students[x + j][y + 1];
                students[x + j][y + 1] = temp;
                temp = students[x][y + 2] ; 
                students[x][y + 2] = students[x + j][y + 2];
                students[x + j][y + 2] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

        }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("modified array is:");
    System.out.println(); 
    for(int count1 = 0; count1 < arrlen -1; count1++) 
    {
        for(int count2 = 0; count2 < arrlen -2; count2++) 
        {
            System.out.print(students[count1][count2] + "   \t" );
        }

        System.out.println(); 
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: Usin a 2D array is a horrible way of doing that. Create a Student class, and use a Student array (i.e. `Student[]`. Then google for " how to sort objects in Java".

Comment: Anyway, all you need is `Arrays.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(student -> student[colomb]))`. Note that the proper term is `column`, not `colomb`.

Comment: this code is almost unreadable. You should learn to *reuse code* by using separate methods for code used in several places ...